# Sharepoint Lookup Get values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I searched a lot on the web for my answer but could not find any one. I have an list with invoice and aircraft price list. The lookup works perfect i can select the aircraft type through the invoice list. I also want to be able to select if its a Platform or Hangar price. Can someone help me how i can achieve this?

Here are some screenshots

[image: Add new item Invoice]

[image: Aircraft List with prices]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting some form of cascading drop down fields. These are supported in 2010 Enterprise edition but via the use of info path forms. This requires no code just some GUI based configuration. Unfortunately it's a little more in depth than me explaining it on here so I will provide you to a link for a blog.

[Cascading drop down info path forms](http://blog.erikvl87.nl/2010/10/how-to-create-a-cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Alternatively if you google around cascading drop downs there are plenty of articles involving other methods.

Cheers

Truez

Comment: Thank you very much Truez, I was looking for this..... You helped me out of it.

Cheers,
Mystrymen